# Why doesn't setting IFS shell variable split string into words in a for-loop, unless $(echo ...) is used?

Tags: bash

I would assume that setting `IFS='X'` would cause `bash` to split the string `fooXbarXbaz` into three words: `foo`, `bar`, and `baz`.

However, it only works if the string is provided to the `for`-loop through command substitution: `$(echo fooXbarXbaz)`:

```
$ IFS='X'; for x in fooXbarXbaz; do echo Y${x}Z; done
Yfoo bar bazZ
$ IFS='X'; for x in $(echo fooXbarXbaz); do echo Y${x}Z; done
YfooZ
YbarZ
YbazZ
```

Can someone explain why the first example command fails to split `fooXbarXbaz` into three words, while the second example is successful?

Comment: You can also use `IFS='X'; vars=fooXbarXbaz; for x in $vars; do echo Y${x}Z; done`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`$IFS` is only used for word splitting after unquoted 
expansions.  There is no expansion in `for x in fooXbarXbaz`.  There is however an unquoted expansion in `echo Y${x}Z`, which means that `echo` is called with the three arguments `Yfoo`, `bar` and `bazZ`.  The `echo` utility prints each of its arguments with a space in-between, so you get `Yfoo bar bazZ`.

In the second example, the string is the output of a command substitution, which is an expansion, so the string is split for the loop.

The `IFS` variable is also used for splitting the input to the `read` utility.

Comment: Does `IFS`-based word splitting only occur after expansions in general?

Comment: @Shuzheng Yes, correct. I have corrected the text to say "unquoted expansions". Quoted expansions are not split. Compare `echo $s` and `echo "$s"` with `IFS=X; s=helloXworld`

Comment: @Shuzheng (If I'm correctly reading your question) the (only, AFAIK) use of `IFS` for splitting that may not be occurring after an expansion is with the `read` utility. Try playing with `(IFS=X; read x y; echo "x: $x"; echo "y: $y")`.

Comment: @fra-san That is a correct reading of the manual. I did not mention this as it was not applicable on this particular question, the way I read it. That's splitting input rather than words in a variable or a string.

Comment: @Kusalananda I agree. Actually, my "If I'm correctly reading your question" only referred to the question in the OP's comment to your answer - I haven't been really clear, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

> Can someone explain why the first example command fails to split `fooXbarXbaz` into three words

Because shells aren't supposed to work like that *any more*.

In some ancient times, word splitting happened for plain words too, e.g. with [`heirloom-sh`](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh.html):

```
heirloom-sh$ for foo in 123o456o789; do echo $foo; done
ech: not found
ech: not found
ech: not found
```

Oops, I mean:

```
heirloom-sh$ for foo in 123o456o789; do "echo" $foo; done
123
456
789
```

(Even there the keywords and variable names didn't get split on the `o`s.)

While using `o` or `X` in `IFS` is a bit extreme, it's probably for the best that splitting now only happens for *expansions*.

If you use splitting on purpose, remember that unquoted expansions are also processed for globbing, so things like `*` may cause surprises. Arrays usually work better for handling multiple values.

Answer (score 3):

The GNU bash documentation clearly explains this behavior under [Command Substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html)

> If the substitution appears within double quotes, word splitting and filename expansion are not performed on the results.

Since the second case has a a unquoted substitution, the resultant string `fooXbarXbaz` is subjected to word splitting by the shell by the value of `IFS` set, which splits the word into multiple words.

In the first case `for x in fooXbarXbaz;`, the string is subjected to pathname expansion (aka glob expansion). The shell performs this at a stage much later than word-splitting, after finishing all possible expansions (see [Shell Expansions](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Expansions.html#Shell-Expansions)), so the resultant string is treated literally.

To add further take the case of variable expansion `$var`, which happens before pathname expansion, undergoes same process like your OP

```
IFS='X'; var=fooXbarXbaz; for x in $var; do echo Y${x}Z; done
```

An unquoted variable expansion like command substitution undergoes word splitting by the value of `IFS`. That's why generally we insist on quoting all expansions to avoid unforseen word splitting done by the shell.

Comment: Also remember that an unquoted expansion is split **+ glob**. If you only want the splitting, you need to remove the quotes, but also to disable globbing. So: `IFS=X; set -o noglob; for x in $var; do printf '%s\n' "Y${x}Z"; done` (also remember: don't use `echo` to display arbitrary content).